# Android webview app on ICS getting pixelated

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, pixelate

My android app is working fine on all android devices except in samsung devices having ICS. It's a webview app and the images are getting pixelated on samsung devices having ICS. Any idea on this?

Comment: can you please explain, what do you mean by pixelated ? some images/screenshots will help

Comment: the images no longer remain sharp, you can see some pixels in them, for ex., when you zoom an image a lot you see pixels.

Comment: so how it happens in my case is, if i press and hold my finger on my app for a second, it gets pixelated. Then if i do a click like action, it goes back to normal. So I guess maybe if i can make the app believe every time it tries to make it pixelated that i was actually trying to click then this wont happen. but not sure how i do it. need ur inputs :)

Comment: Update: this happens because of some css transitions in the app like webkit slide animations. but the point is, even if its happening due to this css then why just ICS is making the app pixelated. prior android versions work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution :) 
I just included a line android:hardwareAccelerated="true", in my application tag in xml file. I had to change the project build target to Android 3.0 for this line. And thats it! pixelation issue gone :)