# Jelly Bean webview doesnt scroll smoothly

Tags: android, webview, scroll, android-4.2-jelly-bean

My android webview app never had scrolling issues until the most recent version, Jelly Bean. Scrolling is no longer smooth enough and no acceleration either. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you enabled hardware acceleration in your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using hardware acceleration but that didn't solve this issue. However, i figured the problem and came out with some other solution.
The issue was(as far as I observed), I had a bind touchend (jquery) event on a page which had several clickable elements. Now, while scrolling, somehow the system was trying to work on the bind events on every div element, and hence was slowing down the scroll drastically. 
So i fixed it by unbinding these divs on scroll and rebinding on end of scroll. 
It worked!

P.S.: using hardware acceleration solved some other issue i was facing with ICS & Jelly Bean about which I have posted here (along with this solution) [Android webview app on ICS getting pixelated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11305260/1047337)