# Android WebView Smooth Scroll Conflicts Swipe

Tags: android, jquery, webview

I cannot have smooth scroll if I simply use webview to include my websites.
As [Jelly Bean webview doesnt scroll smoothly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573706/jelly-bean-webview-doesnt-scroll-smoothly?answertab=votes#tab-top) suggested, I checked any jQuery binding event I have with javascript.

I notice that all binding events(popup,expandable list) will be fine except the following swipe event:

```
$( document ).on( "swipeleft", page, function() {
        $( page ).cjSwipe( 'on', function(swipeLeft) { // this is a mobile plug-in to disable swipe on desktop
            document.location.href = next + ".html";
        });
})
```

So my question is whether I can have both smooth scroll and swipe at the same time, or do I have to sacrifice one to get the other?
Thanks for any help/suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem already and solved it this way:

in `OnGestureListener` in `onFling` method return `false` instead of `true` or other!